# output not displaying after piping with fork and exec

Tags: c++11, pipe, fork, exec

I am trying to create a function which runs one command and then pipes the output to a second command and runs that. I'm running the function in an infinite loop. The problem is, the function works the first time, but doesn't show anything after that.
For example, when I run `ls | wc -l`, the first time it shows the correct results, but when I run it after that I get no output.

Here is my function (parsing is handled in another function):

```
void system_pipe(std::string command1, std::string command2)
{
    int status;
    int fd[2];
    int fd2[2];
    pipe(fd);

    int pid = fork();
    // Child process.
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<char> temp = string_to_char(command1);
        char *name[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", temp.get(), NULL};

        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        execvp(name[0], name);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Parent process.
    else
    {
        std::shared_ptr<char> temp = string_to_char(command2);
        char *name[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", temp.get(), NULL};   

        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        //my_system(command2);

        // Fork and exec a new process here.
        int pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0)
        {
            execvp(name[0], name);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
        }
    }

    if (status)
        std::cout << "Bad" << std::endl;
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
while(true)
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    pair<string, string> commands = parse(line);
    system_pipe(commands.first, commands.second);
}
```

Why is the function only working correctly on the first loop? What is changing after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else
 { 
        std::shared_ptr<char> temp = string_to_char(command2);
        char *name[] = {"/bin/bash", "-c", temp.get(), NULL};   

        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        //my_system(command2);
```

That was not your intention, I believe. dup2 had to be called in child.

```
int pid2 = fork();
if (pid2 == 0)
{
    dup2(fd[0], 0); // here.
    execvp(name[0], name);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The second problem is that you leave your pipe files open. 
This is not a good coding sample, but it's only to illustrate how it should work.

```
// ( g++ -std=c++11  )
// type `ls | grep file.cxx`
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <array> 
#include <memory>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void replace_with ( std::string command )
{
    char exec_name [] = "bash" , arg [] = "-c" ;
    char * line [] = { exec_name , arg , &command[ 0 ] , nullptr } ;
    execvp( exec_name , line ) ;
}

void pipeline ( const std::string& command0 , const std::string& command1 )
{
    std::array< int , 2 > pipe_fd ; enum { READ_END , WRITE_END } ; 

    if ( pipe( pipe_fd.data() ) ) throw std::runtime_error( "can't create a pipe" ) ;

    int id = fork() ;
    if ( id < 0 ) { for ( auto each : pipe_fd ) close( each ) ;
                    throw std::runtime_error( "can't create a child" ) ; }

    if ( ! id ) /* child */
    {
        close( pipe_fd[ READ_END ] ) ; 
        dup2( pipe_fd[ WRITE_END ] , STDOUT_FILENO ) ;
        close( pipe_fd[ WRITE_END ] ) ; //

        replace_with( command0 ) ;
    }
    else /* parent */
    {
        close( pipe_fd[ WRITE_END ] ) ;
        waitpid( id , nullptr , 0 ) ;
        int id_second = fork () ;
        if ( id_second > 0 ) waitpid( id_second , nullptr , 0 ) ;
        else if ( ! id_second ) /* child */ 
        {
            dup2( pipe_fd[ READ_END ] , STDIN_FILENO ) ;
            close( pipe_fd[ READ_END ] ) ; //
            replace_with( command1 ) ;
        }

        close( pipe_fd[ READ_END ] ) ;
    }
}

int main () try
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::string command0 , command1 ;
        getline( std::cin , command0 , '|' ) ;
        getline( std::cin , command1 ) ;
        pipeline( command0 , command1 ) ;
    }

} catch ( const std::runtime_error& e ) 
  { std::cerr << e.what() ; return - 1 ; }
```